# Actionbar tabs with Actionbarcompact 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

I am building an app with actionbartabs using v7 and v4 libs, The problem I'm having is i am not able to click on any tabs on Android 2.3.3 emulator but will work fine on 4.x+. they always throw me error inflating layout.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                // About Rated fragment activity
                return new AboutFragment();
            case 1:
                // Achievements fragment activity
                return new AchievementFragment();
            case 2:
                // Constituency fragment activity
                return new ConstituencyFragment();

            case 3:
                // Party fragment activity
                return new PartyFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above code builds and runs smoothly on 2.3.3 emulator however slide to access next page (or) click on any other tabs it crashes and exits
Here is my simple party fragment which just returns a textview

```
public class PartyFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_party, container, false);
    return rootView;    
 } }
```

here is my stack trace

```
    01-09 13:21:51.377: D/dalvikvm(365): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 80K, 51% free 2755K/5511K, external 7190K/8940K, paused 40ms
    01-09 13:21:51.407: E/dalvikvm-heap(365): 6401360-byte external allocation too large for this process.
    01-09 13:21:51.417: D/dalvikvm(133): GC_EXPLICIT freed 19K, 50% free 2957K/5895K, external 2793K/3250K, paused 715ms
    01-09 13:21:51.447: E/GraphicsJNI(365): VM won't let us allocate 6401360 bytes
01-09 13:21:51.447: D/dalvikvm(365): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1K, 51% free 2753K/5511K, external 7190K/8940K, paused 23ms
01-09 13:21:51.447: D/skia(365): --- decoder->decode returned false
01-09 13:21:51.457: D/AndroidRuntime(365): Shutting down VM
01-09 13:21:51.457: W/dalvikvm(365): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at com.umidtech.tabbacwardcompatible.ConstituencyFragment.onCreateView(ConstituencyFragment.java:25)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  ... 24 more
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1899)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:286)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:173)
01-09 13:21:51.487: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  ... 27 more
01-09 13:21:51.517: W/ActivityManager(60):   Force finishing activity com.umidtech.tabbacwardcompatible/.MainActivity
01-09 13:21:52.036: W/ActivityManager(60): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{407200a8                com.umidtech.tabbacwardcompatible/.MainActivity}
01-09 13:21:53.906: I/Process(365): Sending signal. PID: 365 SIG: 9
01-09 13:21:53.927: I/ActivityManager(60): Process com.umidtech.tabbacwardcompatible (pid 365) has died.
01-09 13:21:53.927: I/WindowManager(60): WIN DEATH: Window{406e6ca8 com.umidtech.tabbacwardcompatible/com.umidtech.tabbacwardcompatible.MainActivity paused=false}
01-09 13:21:54.026: W/InputManagerService(60): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 365 uid 10039
01-09 13:22:02.586: W/ActivityManager(60): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{407200a8 com.umidtech.tabbacwardcompatible/.MainActivity}
```

Comment: properties>buildpath then add jar for appcompac.

Comment: I am building with android studio,so I have added dependecy in gradle